# Replace 30 Images and then stop

Tags: jquery, html

I didn't code for a while so I need to ask this silly question:

I have an Image on a webpage with the following src: "images/santa/1.jpg"

Every 250 milliseconds the "1.jpg" should be replaced with "2.jpg", "3.jpg" and so on until 30 and then stop, and then it should fire the function "thanks", which is not defined yet. What did I do wrong?

```
var theSanta = $('div#main img#theSanta');  

        //case 1: theSanta.attr('src', 'images/santa/1.jpg');

 setInterval(function() {

    for(var i=1; i<31; i++) {
        theSantaSrc = 'images/santa/' + i + '.jpg';
        theSanta.attr('src', theSantaSrc);
    }
}, 500);
```

}

Comment: ID's are unique, so `theSanta` only contains one single image, as jQuery won't find anything than the first element with that ID, as there shouldn't be any more !

Comment: Every half second, your loop runs fully.

Comment: @kei hit the nail on the head, you are looping through all the images in just a few milliseconds all at once every 30 seconds.  You need to keep track of the image counter outside of the setInterval function and not have a loop inside.

Comment: It does replace the image, but only with the last one "30.jpg", with no steps in between..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the for loop and simply count each time the interval runs.

```
var theSanta = $('div#main img#theSanta');  

var count = 1;
var counter = setInterval(function() {        
    theSantaSrc = 'images/santa/' + count + '.jpg';
    theSanta.attr('src', theSantaSrc);

    if (count >= 30) {
       counter.clearInterval();
       alert('Thanks!');
    }
    else count++;
}, 500);
```

Comment: Another episode of "Internet saved my ass at work" - thanks jibsales! I just replaced "count < 30" with "count == 30" so it doesn't run into "31". Here is a picture of a cute kitten for you: http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16100000/Cute-Kitten-kittens-16122951-1280-800.jpg

Comment: Oops! I made the edit to switch the operator. Glad to help and HO HO HO!

Comment: A better xmas gift than the cute kitty would be to give me some reps and accept the answer... though the kitty is cute =)

Answer (score 0):

> What did I do wrong?

Let's look at this code:

```
setInterval(function() {

    for(var i=1; i<31; i++) {
        theSantaSrc = 'images/santa/' + i + '.jpg';
        theSanta.attr('src', theSantaSrc);
    }
}, 500);
```

You define a for-loop inside the setInterval. So every 500 milliseconds, the for-loop is executed 30 times. Get rid of the for loop, you don't need it.

```
var i = 1;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < 31){ // check the step count
        theSantaSrc = 'images/santa/' + i + '.jpg';
        theSanta.attr('src', theSantaSrc);
        i++;
    } else { // stop the interval
        clearInterval(interval);
        thanks(); // execute your thanks function here
    }
}, 500);
```